# How to remove bias or play dumb yourself?

Tags: user-behavior

I know to really assess the design, I have to do usability test. However, I'm wondering there's any way (or checklist, or trick, whatever) to remove bias, even play dumb, and put me in users' shoes to proof-read my design?

Cheers.

Comment: Ask a friend to look at it

Comment: Use personas.. Be objective about it.

Comment: Bowen summed it up well. You're essentially asking for heuristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. If your objective is to overcome bias there is very little you can do about that. It's a property of the human brain to become acclimated to things.

There are a couple checks you can do, but I wouldn't really call them adequate replacements for usability testing.

- You can do a [heuristic evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation) against your design
- You can change all the text on the page to a different language/gibberish and see if the design works without being able to read everything
- Same thing for graphics/colors. Does the design still work with black/white and boxes